# AD Account Will Not Create If Duplicate First Name & Second Name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am creating a script to create users on a domain for one of my clients (NHS in the UK), however it currently refuses to create the AD User & exchange account if the user has a First & Second Name that Already Exists within the AD.

I have already bypassed username duplication by adding a number onto the end of the usernames if they already exist. However, if the first / second name is duplicated it will not create the account.

```cs
$DisplayName = $Surname + " " + $GivenName
$Mail = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + "royalberkshire.nhs.uk"
$MailAlias = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + $DNSRoot2

$SInitial = $Surname[0]
$Initial = $GivenName[0]
$SAMAccountName = $Surname + "" + $Initial
$SAMAccountLower = $SAMAccountName.ToLower()
$UserPrincipalName = $Surname+$Initial
$HD = "U"
$HDir = "\\RBHFILRED002\"
$AC = "Users_01$\"
$DH = "Users_02$\"
$IM = "Users_03$\"
$NS = "Users_04$\"
$TZ = "Users_05$\"

$Folder = if ($SInitial -in 'a','b','c'){$AC}
          elseif ($SInitial -in 'd','e','f', 'g','h'){$DH}
          elseif ($SInitial -in 'i','j','k', 'l','m'){$IM}
          elseif ($SInitial -in 'n','o','p', 'q','r','s'){$NS}
          else {$TZ}

$group1 = "zz Everyone"
$group2 = "Safeboot Domain Users"

$defaultname = $SAMAccountName
$email = $GivenName + "." + $Surname
$i = 1
cls

while ((Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null) {
    $SamAccountName = $defaultname + [string]$i
    $Mail = $email + [string]$i + "@" + "royalberkshire.nhs.uk"
    $i++
}

$NewUserParams = @{
    Path                  = "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk"
    SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
    Name                  = $DisplayName
    DisplayName           = $DisplayName
    GivenName             = $GivenName
    Surname               = $Surname
    EmailAddress          = $Mail
    UserPrincipalName     = "$SAMAccountName@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk"
    Title                 = $title
    HomeDrive             = $HomeDrive
    HomeDirectory         = "$HDir$Folder$SAMAccountName"
    Description           = $Description
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
    PasswordNeverExpires  = $false
    AccountPassword       = $defpassword
    Enabled               = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewUserParams
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
Start-Sleep -s 10
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName

cls
echo "Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox.."
Start-Sleep -s 30

Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
cls
```

Any Ideas?

**EDIT 1 - Error output:**

```
Name        : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
PSVersion   : 1.0
Description : Admin Tasks for the Exchange Server

Name        : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Support
PSVersion   : 1.0
Description : Support Tasks for the Exchange Server

This tool is to be used for creating User Accounts for the RBFT Domain under
Ultima Business Solutions only. If this applies, please hit any key to continue.





Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' under: 'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'. At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:140 char:9
+ While ((Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyCon ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TimmsJ1:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' u nder: 'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm  ands.GetADUser

New-ADUser : An attempt was made to add an object to the directory with a name that is already in use At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:166 char:1
+ New-ADUser @NewUserParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Timms James,...tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An attempt was made to add an object to the dire ctory with a name that is already in use,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Managem ent.Commands.NewADUser

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' under: 'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'.
At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:167 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TimmsJ1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGro upMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Micros oft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TimmsJ1' under: 
'DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk'. At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:169 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TimmsJ1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Please Wait Whilst We Find The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox..
Enable-Mailbox : The operation couldn't be performed because object 'TimmsJ1' couldn't be found on 'rbhdc8red002.rbbh-tr.nhs.uk'.
At C:\Users\timmsj\Desktop\Scripts\User_Creation\RBFT_UC_Dev.ps1:175 char:1
+ Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Enable-Mailbox], Manage mentObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 637D7B43,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Recipient Tasks.EnableMailbox

Username:
TimmsJ1

Password:
Welcome123

Email:
James.Timms1@royalberkshire.nhs.uk

Job Title - Department:
Test - Ultima

Home Directory:
\\RBHFILRED002\Users_05$\TimmsJ1

You will need to manually set the new user's group memberships. Please Do This
Before Sending The User's Account Details.


Press Any Key To Close
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Does it give any clues to why it didn't create the account?  Also, do you get the same problem if you manually create a user with the same details that fail in your script?

Comment: @boxdog let me run my error log, and i'll edit the post.

Comment: @boxdog I have edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `-Name` sets not only the attribute `name` but also `cn` (common name), which must be unique just like `sAMAccountName`. To fix the issue change this:

```
$NewUserParams = @{
    Path                  = "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk"
    SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
    Name                  = $DisplayName
    DisplayName           = $DisplayName
    ...
}
```

into this:

```
$NewUserParams = @{
    Path                  = "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk"
    Name                  = $SAMAccountName
    DisplayName           = $DisplayName
    ...
}
```

When omitting `-SamAccountName` the value of the parameter `-Name` is automatically assinged as the `sAMAccountName` too.

Comment: This works perfectly Thank You!

Another thing if possible, it understandably throws up an error when it states the username can't be detected (before making the account)
My silentlyContinue doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @JamesTimms Using `-Identity` will always throw an error if the account doesn't exist. Use `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SAMAccountName'"` for checking silently.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you, you have genuinely helped me complete the final part of my script.